# Associative arrays: how to get rid of duplicates?

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [attribute_name] => Appliances
            [attribute_value] => Washer
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [attribute_name] => Appliances
            [attribute_value] => Dryer
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [attribute_name] => Appliances
            [attribute_value] => Dishwasher
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [attribute_name] => Appliances
            [attribute_value] => Microwave
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [attribute_name] => Console
            [attribute_value] => Xbox360
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [attribute_name] => Console
            [attribute_value] => PS3
        )
)
```

I want to produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [attribute_name] => Appliances
            [attribute_value] => Washer, Dryer, Dishwasher, Microwave
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [attribute_name] => Console
            [attribute_value] => Xbox360, PS3
        )
)
```

How is this achieved in PHP?

Here's my final code based on @andrewtweber's original solution:

http://codepad.org/E4WFnkbc

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Will the duplicates always come in pairs? Will the duplicates always be consecutive? Will there always be pairs?

Comment: @MarkReed - never saw that link before, going to have to use it from now on. :)

Comment: Can I suggest instead of combining them into a comma-separated list, that you combine them into another sub-array? `array(0=> array('attribute_name' => "Appliances", 'attribute_value' => array('Washer','Dryer','Diswasher')))`

Comment: Or what about `array( 'Appliances' => array('Washer', 'Dryer', 'Dishwasher') )`

Comment: @MarkReed, I will post what I've tried in after addressing other comments.  For what it's worth, I've found leaving the floor open for answering a good way to get fresh responses.  Adding more detail in the past seems to come with slower response time.  I admit, its just a feeling, not an accurate observation of mine.

Comment: @andrewtweber, that would work too.

Comment: @Michael, again that works as well.  Combining seems to be the tricky part for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$new_arr = array();

foreach( $arr as $data ) {
    if( !isset($new_arr[$data['attribute_name']]) ) {
        $new_arr[$data['attribute_name']] = array();
    }
    $new_arr[$data['attribute_name']][] = $data['attribute_value'];
}
```

This will give you

```
array( 'Appliances' => array( 'Washer', 'Dryer', 'Dishwasher' ) );
```

http://codepad.org/m6l3je0H

Comment: That totally worked!  I had an issue with the is_array part throwing an indexing error so I just used isset instead.  I've posted an example that also makes the output into a string for craps and laughs.

Comment: Ah good point - probably just a notice right? But I'll update my answer in case anybody else comes across it